# Webpack production request https

Tags: reactjs, webpack, axios

I have a problem. I am using axios to make a request to a http target, but when building the code, the bundle request to a https as show in the picture.

Maybe I need to do some configuration on my webpack config.

**correct target:** http://ip-api.com/json

**wrong target:** https://ip-api.com/json

[image: Get Request]

***webpack.prod.config.js***

```
const common = require('./webpack.common.config')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'production',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_module/
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [{
          loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
        }, {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            modules: true
          }
        }, {
          loader: 'sass-loader'
        }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  externals: {
    axios: 'axios',
    react: 'React',
    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM'
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './template.prod.html'
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'main-bundle-[hash].css'
    })
    // new FaviconsWebpackPlugin({
    //   logo: './public/static/img/favicon.png',
    //   inject: true
    // })
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solutions. I removed `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests" />` from my **template.prod.html** and the problem was solved.